# I need to perform subtraction on an alphanumeric in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, alphanumeric

I need to subtract 1 or more from an alphanumeric as I import data into SQL.

Example:

```
=IF({src::Comments}="DUPLICATE",STRCAT("X",RIGHT({src::Sample #},6)-1),"NULL")
```

Where the `src::Sample #` is a 7 character alphanumeric.

I thought this should work, but the action fails to return a value.

Comment: Which dbms?????  This is probably one of the most important info.  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: acQuire over SQL 2012 (a geologic data management system)

Answer (score 0):

So after playing with this I found the following that works,

=IF({src::Comments}="DUPLICATE",STRCAT("X",DIFF(RIGHT({src::Sample #},6),1)),"NULL")

Using the DIFF function at the start of argument in the second part of the STRCAT function returns a valid result.